# How to properly make a Ken Burns effect using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently tried the Ken Burns effect with this little jQuery plugin: [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/).

The problem with that plugin is that when the motion is too slow it looks really bad. This is due to the fact that the image can only move 1 pixel at the time...

I tried to do my own slideshow and I have the exact same problem. I then thought that this is normal... since we can only move an image pixel by pixel.

But I just found this slider: [Estro](http://codecanyon.net/item/estro-jquery-ken-burns-swipe-effect-slider/full_screen_preview/235111)
Estro looks perfect to me. I wonder why it looks so smooth and how can I make mine look that good.

How can my Ken Burns effect be as good as Estro's one.

Answer (score 2):

Without diving into the code for each one, if I were creating this I would use jQuery's animate() function.  Using this function you can fine tune your slideshow by determining the distance and speed of the images' movement.  For example this would move your image 50px to the up and to the left in 2 seconds:

```
$(".slideshow_image").animate({
    'left':     '-=50px',
    'top':      '-=50px',
    'opacity':  0
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, to add some more info the image would need to be positioned absolutely, and you might want to add a container box, so that it looks a bit better. http://jsfiddle.net/vwSTV/1/

Comment: @SSHThis *the image would need to be positioned absolutely*: except you use margin ;)

Answer (score 2):

JS Code which uses HTML5 Canvas :
http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2011/2/26/ken-burns-effect-with-javascript-and-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a relatively old post, but I thought I'd reflect on it as I'm looking for the same answer..
Thanks for the Estro slider link, it's very smooth indeed, and I think I just found out how they do it: on top of the image tag they create an HTML5 canvas that lets you do basic 2D transformations - like dynamic resizing.

This way you don't need to worry about the fact that you can only handle full pixels. Also it might work without a canvas, but not using '-=50'-type animations, but scaling.

Have a look at [KenBurner](http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/kenburner/) as an example.

I hope it helps some of you out there..

Comment: This does not answer the question, the link does not work anymore and links to a commercial project, -1...

Comment: Thanks @jpoppe for commenting on a 4 year old answer. I'm sorry that the link has been shut down in the meantime, please find an archive [link here](http://previous.themepunch.com/kenburner-responsive/light.html). I hope this helps even though it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Just to compliment your comment, I did some more digging around on this, and to answer OP's question of "How can my Ken Burns effect be as good as Estro's one.", [here is the link](http://previous.themepunch.com/kenburner-responsive/kb-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.kenburn.js) to the original version of the Ken Burns plugin. Again, I hope this helps someone - not trying to revive an ancient post.